# Dart isolate messages delay

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I am learning about isolates at the moment and I'm trying to get an example to send messages from the main isolate to the worker isolate and vice versa. I can currently get messages to flow in both directions but the messages coming from the worker isolate seem to process immediately in the main isolate's `listen` callback but while the messages from main to the worker are being sent, they are not being processed by the worker isolate's `listen` callback until the worker isolate has finished all it's work.

***Are the messages supposed to flow in real time?*** I have a working gist for the current flutter/dart versions (October 2022) that shows messages from the worker in real time and then all the responses to the worker processing all at once...

[image]

***Are the messages to the worker being blocked by it's busy for loop?*** Here is my sample gist with the working code...
https://gist.github.com/hootyjeremy/44a9b3404398b881a3e9fb255a6c7bfd

Comment: Don't use `sleep` in general since it stops the event loop. If you want to "pause for some amount of time" you should use `Future.delayed` to construct a "slow" Future and then await on that. By doing so, you are still allowing the event loop to run in the background.

Comment: Oh my stars. That seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot. I was wondering if sleep was having that effect and also earlier tried an expensive for loop instead but it also blocked. But I will think on this solution. Thanks again.